# Which is the fastest course for learning Esperanto?

Tags: learning, course

I have heard people complain that Duolingo takes too long to reach a basic level. Is there a course that teaches the basics very fast so one can attain a high level quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way I learned it was pretty fast: read through the basics (any article casually explaining Esperanto), get some reference material (dictionary, correlative table, prefix/suffix overview...) and then just start chatting. You will be on a good level in no-time.

Other than than, it seems to me [esperanto12.net](https://esperanto12.net) is pretty good and fast.

Also most courses over mail, and I include Kurso de Esperanto in this, are pretty good to do quickly.